# how do I get an Android view to take up "remaining" space?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that has a header at the top of the screen, some button elements at the bottom of the screen and then I'd like to devote the middle (whatever is left over) to a scroll view.

I know how to do everything except for how to assign a height to the ScrollView that would take into account what is above and below it and then take residence in between.

Would love to see an XML sample for how to accomplish this effect.

TIA

Comment: what you have done with XML layout so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use relative layout for this.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header">
    <!--Header elements here-->
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/footer">
    <!--Footer element here-->
  </LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
              android:layout_below="@+id/header">
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thx for solution which works great. Can you, or anyone else, explain why simply specifying that the `scrollview` is `layout_below` the `header` and the `footer` to be `layout_below` the `scrollview` should not achieve the same result when my `footer` has `layout_height` of 50dp? Why might android interpret that differently than your solution?

Comment: from my understanding, it should work even if you have a `footer` with `layout_height` of 50dp. Maybe there is something else that could have caused the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't want to switch to a `RelativeLayout,` I would think you could use `android:layout_weight` attributes to distribute screen real estate.

Answer (score 1):

So in this case, you want to have Header(Top), scrollview(middle) and Buttons(Bottom), for this just take a **RelativeLayout**.